# Getting revenge against a more powerful player

Tags: clash-of-clans

Someone attacked me and destroyed 100% of my base. After this attack, I got very angry and I want revenge, but his town hall is level 7 and my town hall is level 6. In five days, my town hall will be upgraded to 7, but I want revenge quickly because I'm worried that revenge button will disappear.

All my walls are lvl 6 and all my defenses are fully upgraded, but he attacked me using giant lvl 7 in clan castle.

How can I get revenge on someone who is more powerful than me? Please give me some ideas.

Comment: If they are too powerful, you simply can't. Better deal with it.

Comment: They are more powerful but not very much , what is your idea ?

Comment: Maybe you could earn at least 1 star? It would count as a victory and it not that hard if the enemy isn't much stronger.

Comment: Try to snipe one storage atleast. Remember you also have a castle with 20 capacity(if fully upgraded). Ask your generous clanmates to donate some powerful troops and take it to revenge. And that button will always be there. Defense log has a limit, if you get attacked more , then that log will be lost.

Comment: Maybe don't get so angry about people attacking you, because that's part of the game? Pick fights that you can actually win, and you'll benefit in the long run.

Comment: "Revenge is a dish best served cold". Don't haste it. Wait until the right moment when you have the power and the opportunity to pay him back properly.

Comment: It's not always worth it to revenge. I only revenge if my opponent has enough resources to outweigh the cost to produce an army that could get said resources. At your level resources are more important than trophies, really.

Comment: always keep in mind: as you are getting stronger, he will also upgrade his stuff and become stronger

Comment: Should all the people you attacked be angry at you too?

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to revenge him fast, as long as his name is in your defence log, you can revenge him. however, I would advice asking fellow clan mates for troops as well as advice to defeat him. The base of the person is what is important, there are many bases which can withstand full raids, and from a Town Hall below you, you won't get a loss usually. I myself am a TH9 but fear going against Th10s, especially ones which are maxed, since infernos can kill your troops very fast. However, this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Before the time you're strong enough to hit him hard, the record to do revenge is already out of sight. Revenge is possible as long as the record of the enemy attack is in the list of defenses. The list will hold up the last 30 attacks and last till the end of the season (every 2 weeks).

My advise advise to you is to spend your troops on a base with a lot of loot and let him and your emotions go.

Answer (score -3):

All I can say is getting your town destroyed in Castle Clash is all part of the game. But if you want to be able to try and destroy their town I would try making your town stronger and upgrade your troops. Then maybe you might be able to defeat stronger opponents.

Comment: Wrong Game Mate, and it's not really helping the OP ::/

Comment: i meant clash of clans

Comment: Even so, it's not meeting the OP's question at all